# PHPで、.htaccessのIPアドレスを動的に制御したい

Tags: php, .htaccess

**現状**
・debug.phpへは管理者のIPアドレスからのみアクセス出来るよう設定しています
(管理者のIPアドレスは、不定期で随時変更されるプロバイダ契約)
・IPアドレスが変更された場合、debug.phpへアクセス出来なくなるので、アドレス変更に気が付きます
・気が付いたら、https://www.cman.jp/network/support/go_access.cgi へアクセスして、IPアドレスを手動でコピペして、下記.htaccessのIPアドレス値を手動で書き換えて、.htaccessをFTPアップロードしています

**.htaccess**

```
<Files ~ "^debug\.php$">
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 111.222.33.444
</Files>
```

---

**やりたいこと**
・IPアドレス変更に気がついたら、予め指定したページへアクセスすること等により、PHPで.htaccessのIPアドレスを動的に変更できれば便利なのに、と思い、質問しました
・IPアドレス変更される度に自動処理されればベストですが、そこまで出来なくても、IPアドレス変更に気がついた際、手作業で処理する負担を少しでも減少させる方法があれば知りたいです

Comment: 「何の」IPアドレスが変更されたら、なのでしょうか。それはどうやって検出できるのでしょうか(今はどうやって「気が付」くのですか)。自分ではどこまで実現できていて、どんなところでつまづいているのでしょうか。質問を編集して追記してください。

Comment: suzukisさんの仰っていることに同意します。また、他の観点から言うとhtaccessをかけると言う事はアクセスに制限をかけていると言う事だろうと思いますが、IPが変わった時点でアクセスが弾かれるかと思います。どこで、どうやって検知するのでしょうか？htaccessの許可の部分だけではなく拒否している部分も知りたいですね。

Answer (score 3):

あくまで簡易なアクセス制限で十分、という前提での回答です

1. アクセス元のIPアドレスを取り出す。
2. そのIPアドレスを埋め込んだ.htaccessファイルを作成する。

というwebから呼び出せるスクリプトをサーバにおき、変更したいタイミングで人力でブラウザからアクセスするか、ブラウザで開きっぱなしにしておいてmeta refreshで自動リロードさせるか、タスクスケジューラやcronなんかを使って自動でアクセスすればよいでしょう。

1はPHPであれば`$_SERVER`変数から取り出せます。
2はプログラミングの練習課題みたいな処理ですのでどんな参考書にでも載ってるでしょう。

まじめにセキュリティ機能として実現するのであれば、上記では全く不十分です。どの程度のセキュリティレベルが必要かもわかりませんし、その認識が正しいかどうかの判断もできませんので、その場合は専門家に相談されることをお勧めします。

Answer (score 0):

おそらく自宅（か会社か）のWAN側アドレスが変更された場合に自動でレンタルサーバーに.htaccessをアップロードしたいといったところでしょうか。
問題はあなたの環境のルーターからどうやってWAN側アドレスの変更を検知するかですが、
1.ルーターにそう言った機能があるのならそれを使う。
2.ルーターの管理画面へHTTP接続できるなら定期的に接続し、情報を読み取る。
3.アドレス教えてくれる外部サイトに定期的にリクエストして情報をもらう。
まあ現実的には3.でしょうか。しかし専用APIがあり短い間隔のリクエストを許してくれるようなサービスでなければ迷惑がかかるかもしれません。
そこであなたのレンサバにallow from Allなところを作ってそこに接続元アドレスを返すAPIを置いてはどうでしょうか。

もし私が見当違いな回答をしていたら、それはあなたの質問が悪いです。
回答者に予想、想像をさせないように質問をしましょう。